GradleException The APK could not be saved into HMS console
I'm trying to upload the APK through AG Connect API using the Gradle Plugin https://github.com/yamilmedina/appgallery-publisher.
Everything was working fine for months, until now that I'm receiving the error:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: The APK could not be saved into HMS console. 

I was searching in Google to find any related error, but didn't find anything.
Has anyone else encountered the same error while uploading an APK to App Gallery?
Thanks in advance for your help!
